# Weighted Average for a-b & ((a-b)/a)

Tags: python, statistics, average, weighted, weighted-average

How do you calculate weighted average for: S, where S = a-b ?

I understand that if a and b have the same weights, i would compute S = a-b and then use the weights to compute weighted average of S.

But here I have the weight vectors for vector a and vector b. What weights do I use for S?

On the same note, what if S = ((a-b)/a) ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a weights vector that haves the same dimentions of `S`.

For example:

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([6, 7, 4, 10])
S = a - b
```

Then define a weight vector with the same lenth of S and compute the weighted average:

```
weights = np.array([2, 1, 6, 5])
avg = sum(S * weights) / sum(weights)
# avg = -3.642857
```

This weights vector depends on the problem you are trying to solve. For example it can be the substraction of `a` and `b` weights, their sum, etc.

For `S = (a - b) / a`  repeat the previous steps.

Comment: Hi Matias, I understand how to compute weighted average. To clarify my question: I want to know what weights 'Ws' to use for computing weighted average of S, given that I know the weight vectors for a and b : Wa and Wb.
If a and b had same weights, I would use that as weights for S as well.

Comment: I think you want to use the substraction of weights for ```S = a - b```, ```W = Wa - Wb``` and for ```S = (a - b) / a ``` you should compute ```W = (Wa - Wb) / Wa```.